# Issues with Markdown Syntax Highlighting in Neovim

Tags: markdown, syntax-highlighting, neovim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am currently trying to start writing Markdown in Neovim. However, the syntax highlighting is messed up. Specifically, whenever I have a less than sign inside a LaTeX block, everything after it is being highlighted (likely because it is being considered an HTML tag).

When I compile the code into a PDF, everything works as expected, including all of the LaTeX code. As a result, my conclusion is that the code itself is fine, and the syntax highlighting is messed up.

Is there any way that I could fix this issue with the Neovim syntax highlighting?

Comment: what does your example markdown look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing the dev version of the markdown syntax plugin, from https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown

I'm using Neovim and Plug, so I added the following to `~/config/nvim/init.vim`, restarted nvim and ran `:PlugInstall`:

```
" Development version of core markdown syntax.
Plug 'tpope/vim-markdown'
```

This fixed issues for me when indented text following a bullet would show as code; it may or may not fix your problem. If it doesn't you should consider opening a ticket on that github repo, providing the author with your markdown.

Comment: Installing the most recent version of  `'tpope/vim-markdown'` also resolved issues for me! I'm using Vim 9.0.

Comment: Using nvim + Treesitter for Markdown also works.